# Product serial number generation when product is selected MVC4

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, generator

I want to create an auto generated serial number when the user selects the product ID from the drop down box.

So for instances when the User selects Product ID "1" it will produce the serial number "SN/2015/01".

Ive seen people using SQL Functions but i would prefer not.

Any suggestions? i could use selectedIndex to get the value from the drop down box but rest im sort of stuck on making clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string.Format("SN/{0}/{1}", DateTime.Now.Year, selectedProductId)
```

If you want to get `"01"` out of `1`, then you can use `.ToString("D2")` method. More formatting of numbers are given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, it very well could be. At least the complexity should come out of this.

Comment: thanks @AD.Net :) exactly what i was looking for :) ill admit im a bit of a novice so sorry if it is a noobish question :)

Comment: This would generate SN/2015/1 rather than SN/2015/01

Comment: @Magnus that was only example wise, i just needed a way of adding a format for the SN, the rest i can do on my own :)